# OAuth2 Authorization grant flow not refreshing expired access/ID tokens - Spring Security

Tags: spring-security, oauth-2.0, openid-connect, refresh-token, sessionend

When a user's access and ID tokens expire, they should be considered invalid and refreshed using the refresh token. If unable to do so, the user's session should be expired.  *(stating from the issue itself) *

Issue Reference - https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/6814

Question -
Any leads on how to customise this for now?

Framework Details:

- There is a UI Application which servers as 'Client'
  [Sample Client configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gNOTv.png)
- There are multiple 'Resource Servers'
  [Sample Resource Server 1 Configurations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oenOe.png)

Comment: You can handle it from client side. Once a request fail as unauthorized request (token expired) initiate a new request for a new token using the refresh token.

Comment: @Phoenician - please explain- _Once a request fail as unauthorized request (token expired)_ . The statements is contradictory to my understanding i.e. Once User is Authenticated -> Session is created -> Access tokens are never verified --> So request never fails in our application.

Comment: You're mixing things here.. check this out "https://dzone.com/articles/oauth-20-vs-session-management" to understand the difference between session/token and how they work together.
Never less, if your application is using token then you will require to refresh it once expired. This job can be done from front-end side.